# NEMA L5-30R in a 4 inch box

Tags: electrical, receptacle, junction-box

I need some help.
Is there an adapter for 4 inch box, to install single gang NEMA L5-30R receptacle. Also, is there a cover for it?

I need to install NEMA L5-30R for our 120 volt, 30 amp, APC UPS.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a 4x4 box … it is a 2-gang mud ring already attached to a 4x4 box.  The mud ring functionally transforms the 4x4 into a 2-gang box, with the same bolt pattern as any other 2-gang box.

So your real question is, **how do I mount a receptacle centered on a 2-gang box?**

And the answer is, you use a receptacle designed for that, which has a very wide yoke designed to catch the top and bottom screw holes of both gangs.  Such as the Pass & Seymour 3802, being one example.

That is not what you have. Your receptacle is designed to live in 1 gang only.

So the next question is: what wiring is in the box?  Because if this is the only socket in this box, you will need to either get a "designed to be centered" NEMA 5-30, or a rare offset cover with a 5-30 on one side and blank on the other.  It is much easier to find a cover with 5-30 in one gang and the standard socket opening in the other gang.

If it's only #12 cable coming into the box, you need a 20A breaker. You can read NEC 210.21 and 210.23 carefully for why a 30A socket might be allowed on a 20A breaker.  So you can simply put a normal duplex 20A receptacle next to the 30A receptacle and call it good.

If you are under NEC and not IBC, there is no limit on the number of 30A receptacles on a circuit. So you could simply get a second one and place them side by side.

Otherwise, I would try to find the "designed to be centered in 2-gang" NEMA 5-30 and use that cover.

If push comes to shove, you can bust a lot of drywall and change that 2-gang mud ring to a 1-gang, but a) that's a PITA that will need drywlall and repaint, and b) it might put you afoul of the receptacle spacing requrements in a dwelling.

Comment: Thank you, I figured that out after posting this. I'm currently looking for a cover. As far as wiring goes, there is a 10-3 wire from the 30 Amp breaker, to that receptacle. Since all I need is 120 volt outlet, I was just gonna cap the red wire on both ends, and use a dual 30 Amp breaker with the link removed ( I need two 120v 30 amp outlets).

Comment: Not allowed to remove the handle tie and it doesn’t matter anyway.  Handle ties don't cause common trip if that's your concern.   An internal mechanism does.   You could just make a MWBC out of that, and put the red wire on another socket.   Dual 30 is an easier faceplate to find anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods to accomplish this.  First is just to mount receptacle on one side of the 2 gang box, get a nylon (unbreakable) 2 gang blank wall plate, and drill out the hole to fit.  Other option is to find a 1 gang FLAT mud ring (can be hard to find) attach it over the 2 gang hole, and finish as normal.  This will leave part of the steel mud ring exposed on each side with a single gang wall plate.
If you are ok with it not being picture perfect on the trim, you can remove the 2 gang mud ring and finish with a raised industrial cover.